# Como salvar array de bytes em arquivo no PHP?

Tags: php, array, arquivo

Tenho um *array* de *bytes* que é uma imagem que está salvo no BD, qual método uso para salvar no disco rígido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa [empacotar](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) o *array* e [gravar](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php). Bem a grosso modo já que você não deu detalhes do que deseja, nem demonstrou o que já fez você pode fazer assim:

```
foreach ($imagem as $byte) {
    $binario .= pack("C", $byte); 
}
$arquivo = fopen("arquivo.bin", 'wb');
fwrite($arquivo, $binario);
fclose($arquivo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/WriteBinary.php).

O jeito exato pode variar de acordo com sua necessidade.

Se o formato já estiver em binário poder apenas fazer a gravação:

```
$arquivo = fopen("arquivo.bin", 'wb');
fwrite($arquivo, $imagem);
fclose($arquivo);
```

Comment: Na verdade é que eu preciso criar uma miniatura dessa imagem que está no BD. Primeiro pesquisei na internet algumas classes que redimensionam essa imagem, achei a classe canvas feita por um brasileiro, eu quero usar ela, mas essa classe nao le array de bytes, ou seja,  primeiro quero salvar a foto na pasta, e depois eu carrego a foto com a classe canvas redimensiono ela, e salvo novamente no mesmo local.

Comment: @JuarezA.FrancoJunior Mas por que você não disse isso na pergunta? Você perguntou outra coisa! Sugiro que poste uma pergunta separada perguntando como gerar uma miniatura a partir de uma imagem que está no banco.

Comment: Por que gerar eu creio que consigo, mas vou reformular em uma nova pergunta mais detalhadamente, outros podem passar por isso. Obrigado. Mas antes vou testar a solução de bigown

Comment: @bigown o foreach não reconheceu o array de bytesesta mostrando seguinte mensagem Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Você não postou nada do que você fez. Agora você está dizendo que não deu certo, mas eu não sei o que você fez. Fica difícil ajudar assim. Você tem que dar informações. Muito provavelmente o que você passou sequer é um *array* conforme você falou.

Comment: Consegui salvar, nao foi preciso o foreach

Comment: Então já está em formato binário.

Comment: deve ser isso eu pego do BD e achei que vinha em array de bytes não é isso?. Obrigado @bigown

Comment: Pode ser, mas como você não passou detalhes, eu tive que supor.

Comment: Mas de qualquer forma essa solução funcionou obrigado.