# Como criar um Thumbnail de uma imagem que está salva no BD?

Tags: php, imagem

Tenho uma imagem salva no BD preciso saber como Redimensionar ela, como salvar ela em uma pasta.

Comment: A parte de salvar já foi perguntada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47101/como-salvar-array-de-bytes-em-arquivo-no-php, portanto esta parte está duplicada.

Comment: Uma palavra : A função [imagecopyresized](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopyresized.php). Daí é só usar a função que carrega a imagem a partir de uma string

Comment: @bigown reformulei a pergunta mais completa pois foi aconselhado a fazer isso. Agora está resolvido desculpe pela confusão. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVIDO**

```
    //Seta endereço da Imagem
    $src = './thumbnail/'.$objeto->id.'.jpg';

    //VERIFICA SE ARQUIVO THUMBNAIL JA EXISTE
    //E Verifica se ARRAY DE BYTES QUE VEM DO BD é nulo
    if(!file_exists($src) && $objeto->foto!=null){
      $arquivo = fopen($src,'wb');
      //Salva foto original
      fwrite($arquivo, $objeto->foto);
      fclose($arquivo);
      //Carrega foto Original
      $img = WideImage::load($src);
      //Redimensiona imagem, usando parametro inside não destorce a imagem
      $img = $img->resize(100,100,'inside');
      //Salva foto com qualidade 80%
      $img->saveToFile($src,80);
   }
//MOSTRAR IMAGEM 
if(file_exists($src)) //verifica se imagem existe, pode ser que não exista foto no BD no entanto é preciso tratar quando nao houver pois não será criado nenhum arquivo
    echo "<img src='$src'/>";
else
    echo "<img src='./thumbnail/default.jpg'/>";
```

Obs.: A Função load do WideImage pode receber binario mas não consegui fazer funcionar fazendo isso **$img = WideImage::load($objeto->foto);**

Agradeço ao @Maniero que me ajudou como salvar arquivo 
[Como salvar array de bytes em arquivo no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47101/como-salvar-array-de-bytes-em-arquivo-no-php)

Comment: Usando WideImage?

Comment: Sim, WideImage. Mas estou testando tbm a classe Canvas.

Comment: Vale a pena dar uma olhada na Intervention Image também. É bem simples de usar https://github.com/Intervention/image